# How can I alternately buffer and flow a live data stream in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have two streams. One is a flow of data (could be any type), the other is a boolean stream acting as a gate. I need to combine these into a stream that has the following behaviour:

- When the gate is open (most recent value was true) then the data
  should flow straight through
- When the gate is closed (most recent value was false) then the data
  should be buffered to be released as individual elements when the
  gate is next open
- The solution should preserve all elements of the data and preserve
  order

I am not really sure how to put this together. The inputs I have been testing with are like this:

```
// a demo data stream that emits every second
var dataStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

// a demo flag stream that toggles every 5 seconds
var toggle = false;
var gateStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Select(_ => toggle = !toggle);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

- Window the data stream using the gate stream as a closing selector
- We can use `DistinctUntilChanged` on the gate stream to ensure no repeated values
- We will also force the gate stream to start closed (false) - it won't affect the output and allows a neat trick
- Then use the overload of `Select` that gives each element an index number. With this we can tell if we need to buffer or just emit the window as is, because we know that even-numbered windows are for buffering (because we made sure the gate stream starts with false)
- We can use `ToList()` to buffer each even window until it closes - this is the actually equivalent of a `Buffer()` that waits until `OnCompleted`
- We use an identity `SelectMany` to flatten the buffered windows
- Finally we concatenate the windows in order to guarantee order is preserved

It looks like this:

```
dataStream.Window(gateStream.StartWith(false).DistinctUntilChanged())
          .Select((w, i) =>  i % 2 == 0 ? w.ToList().SelectMany(x => x) : w)
          .Concat()
          .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Coolest Rx I have seen in a long time.