# Rx for .Net: how to combine Scan with Throttle

Tags: c#, .net, events, system.reactive, reactive-programming

My problem is this: for a given sequence of events I would like to cache their values until there is a pause in the stream. Then, I'm going to process all the cached data in a batch and clear the cache state.

A naive approach to do this would be (not a working code, some errors may exist):

```
struct FlaggedData
{
    public EventData Data { get; set; }
    public bool Reset { get; set; }
}

...

IObservable<EventData> eventsStream = GetStream();
var resetSignal = new Subject<FlaggedData>();

var flaggedDataStream = eventsStream
    .Select(data => new FlaggedData { Data = data })
    .Merge(resetSignal)
    .Scan(
        new List<EventData>(),
        (cache, flaggedData) =>
        {
            if (!flaggedData.Reset())
            {
                cache.Add(flaggedData.Data);
                return cache;
            }

            return new List<EventData>();
        })
    .Throttle(SomePeriodOfTime)
    .Subscribe(batch => 
        {
            resetSignal.OnNext(new FlaggedData { Reset = true});
            ProcessBatch(batch);
        });
```

So here, after receiving any batch for processing, I request a reset of cache. The problem is that because of `Throttle` there could be some data in cache (or so I believe) which will be lost in this case.

What I would like is some operation like:

```
ScanWithThrottling<TAccumulate, TSource>(
    IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> aggregate,
    TimeSpan throttlingSpan)
```

which returns an observable that will reset the accumulated value each time it calls `OnNext` of its subscriber.

Of course, I could write an extension of my own, but question is whether there is some way I could achieve the same effect using standard Rx operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a simple way to go here. Use `Buffer()` to buffer elements based on a throttle like this:

```
var buffered = source.Publish(ps =>        
    ps.Buffer(() => ps.Throttle(SomePeriodOfTime)));
```

This will buffer elements until there has been gap of SomePeriodOfTime and present them as a list. No need to worry about the "reset" aspect, and you won't lose elements.

The use of `Publish` ensures there's a single shared subscription to the source events that can be used by `Buffer` and each `Throttle`. The throttle is the buffer closing function, providing a signal that indicates a new buffer should be started.

Here's a testable version - I'm just dumping out the length of each buffer here and using `Timestamp` to add the timing info, but it's an `IList<T>` that you get on the raw buffered stream. Note how the scheduler is provided as an argument to time based operations to enable testing.

Note, you will need nuget package rx-testing to run this sample, to pull in the Rx test framework and get `TestScheduler` and `ReactiveTest` types:

```
void Main()
{
    var scenarios = new Scenarios();
    scenarios.Scenario1();
}

public class Scenarios : ReactiveTest
{
    public void Scenario1()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var source = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(100, 1),
            OnNext(200, 2),
            OnNext(300, 3),
            OnNext(800, 4),
            OnNext(900, 5),
            OnNext(1400, 6),
            OnNext(1600, 7),
            OnNext(1700, 8),
            OnNext(1800, 9));

    var duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(300);

    var buffered = source.Publish(ps =>        
        ps.Buffer(() => ps.Throttle(duration, scheduler)));

        buffered.Timestamp(scheduler).Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0} Value: {1}",
                 x.Timestamp.Ticks, x.Value.Count()));

        scheduler.Start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah right, buffered windows - why didn't I think of that?

Comment: Out of interest, this question reminds me of another interesting one from a while back - it's a different and more elaborate scenario, but with similar ideas around buffering data until you are ready for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431018/how-can-i-alternately-buffer-and-flow-a-live-data-stream-in-rx

Comment: Well, thank you! Didn't test it, but looks very neat and very working.

Comment: @DaveSexton - I was surprised you didn't do buffered windows either until I saw your 4am coding comment. ;) I am often surprised the next morning that the genius I was creating in the wee small hours turned out to be a cluster-bomb of code, grammar and spelling failures... by any measure that's a pretty good 4am effort! :)

Comment: Good morning, time to start the next day with a bit of embarrassment :-)

Comment: Lesson re-learned: Before posting, always consider the simplest possibilities first, and if you can't do that, then you probably need some rest.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, it seems that you want a `Throttle` that buffers rather than drops.

To solve this problem, let's think about how `Throttle` works:

1. When a value arrives, cache it (replacing any previous value) and start a timer.
2. If another value arrives before the timer elapses, cancel the timer and goto #1.
3. Else when the timer elapses, push the value from the cache.

Your spec:

1. When a value arrives, append it to a buffer and start a timer.
2. If another value arrives before the timer elapses, cancel the timer and goto #1.
3. Else when the timer elapses, push the buffer and create a new buffer.

Thus:

```
var throttled = source.Publish(p => 
  from value in p
  // TODO: Add to buffer (side effect)
  from _ in Observable.Timer(period, scheduler).TakeUntil(p)
  select buffer);  // TODO: Create new buffer (side effect + contention)
```

Notice the race conditions and the possible contention for the hypothetical `buffer` if the specified `scheduler` introduces concurrency.

If the `Timer` elapses when `p` observes a new `value`, then in a naïve implementation it's possible for the latest `value` to leak into the `buffer` before the `buffer` is pushed and a new `buffer` is created. This might be acceptable, though synchronization is necessary no matter how you cut it. And it seems impossible to me to get the exact semantics that you're looking for unless you either extend notifications with timestamps or guarantee thread-affinity for all operations.

Perhaps it makes sense as a good generalized operator anyway. It seems orthogonal enough to me to be included as an Rx primitive, unless I'm just mistaken in my analysis. Consider adding a [work item](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET).

I also distinctly remember discussing a similar operator in the Rx MSDN Forum, probably more than once. Might be worth searching for those discussions.

*Edit: I've changed my mind about using synchronization in this example since the race condition is unavoidable here anyway, assuming `scheduler` introduces concurrency.*

Untested Example:

```
public static IObservable<IList<TSource>> ThrottleBuffered<TSource>(
  this IObservable<TSource> source, 
  TimeSpan period,
  IScheduler scheduler)
{
  return source.Publish(p => 
  {
    var buffer = new List<TSource>();

    return (from _ in p.Do(buffer.Add)
            from __ in Observable.Timer(period, scheduler).TakeUntil(p)
            .Do(_ => buffer = new List<TSource>())
            select buffer);
  });
}
```

Comment: One question: why do you think you'll need an explicit synchronization in this case? You could either regenerate the buffer using immutable list on each new item or use some kind of concurrent queue.

Comment: No matter what the buffer has to be either copied or replaced entirely, so synchronization isn't needed if we just replace it. I had edited my code example after I realized this. The race condition is unavoidable anyway.

Comment: But don't use this solution. It's nice but overly explicit. James' solution is much cleaner.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Why don't you include it in Rxx? ;)

Comment: Not a bad idea :-)  But it's 4AM right now and I'm just about to go to sleep, so I'll have to think about it some more ;)

Comment: I'm leaning away from including this as a discrete operator in Rxx.
You wrote "I would like to [buffer] their values until there is a pause in the stream" which is equivalent in op-speak to `Buffer`->`Throttle`. It's just too easy, as James has shown. I doubt that a strange operator in Rxx would be *more* discoverable.

Comment: @DaveSexton James' approach is not discoverable at all for people less accustomed with Rx. Let's believe in the power of Google...

Comment: I'm strongly considering writing a language expert in JS that accepts a short specification and simply converts nouns to objects and verbs to Rx operators, then does some fix-ups according to simple context analysis. The result will no doubt be better than what novice Rx devs come up with - and what the old MSDN Forum search comes up with :-)

Comment: +1 for Zork. You see before you a bewildering array of operators. What do you want to do?