# How to create an Rx (RxJS) stream that can be switched between single-item and batch-mode?

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

I have an Rx stream that is an outgoing change feed from a particular component.

Occasionally I want to be able to enter a *batch mode* on the stream so that items passed to *onNext* accumulate and are passed on only when the batch mode is exited.

Normally I'll pass single items through the stream:

```
stream.onNext(1); 
stream.onNext(2);
```

There is a 1-to-1 mapping between the items passed to *onNext* and the items received in the *subscribe*, so the previous snippet results in two calls to *subscribe* with the the values 1 and 2.

The *batch mode* I am looking for might work something like this:

```
stream.enterBatchMode();
stream.onNext(1);
stream.onNext(2);
stream.exitBatchMode();
```

In this case I want *subscribe* to only be invoked once with the single concatenated array [1, 2].

Just to reiterate, I need batch mode only sometimes, at other times I pass the non-concatenated items through.

How can I achieve this behaviour with Rx?

NOTE: Previously I was passing arrays through *onNext* although this is mostly so that the type remains the same when in individual mode and when in batch-mode.

Eg:

```
stream.onNext([1, 2, 3]); 
stream.onNext([4, 5, 6]);
```

Subscribe receives [1, 2, 3] then [4, 5, 6], but when in batch-mode subscribe receives the concatenated results [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

So when you look at it this way it's more like *unconcatenated* and *concatenated* modes (as opposed to *individual* and *batch-mode*). But I think the problem is very similar.

Comment: I'm a bit pressed for time today and not the hottest at `rxjs`, but here is a similar problem in `system.reactive` that might inspire an approach to solving this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431018/how-can-i-alternately-buffer-and-flow-a-live-data-stream-in-rx/23431077#23431077 - if someone fancies the translation challenge.

Comment: If you know exactly when to call "start" and "stop" for batch mode between calls to `OnNext`, then why not simply concatenate the arrays yourself before passing them to `OnNext`? (Ok, I guess you've just given an oversimplified example?)

Comment: This is a simplified example. The onNext's that I want to concatenate will be called from multiple other contexts and I intend to enter and exit batch-mode from a higher level in the callstack.

Comment: Thanks James, that example is very close to what I am looking for. I'll see if I can adapt it to my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the spirit of James World's c# solution converted to JavaScript and tailored to your specific question.

```js
var source = new Rx.Subject();
source.batchMode = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(false);
source.enterBatchMode = function() { this.batchMode.onNext(true); };
source.exitBatchMode = function() { this.batchMode.onNext(false); };
var stream = source
  .window(source.batchMode
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .skipWhile(function(mode) { return !mode; }))
  .map(function(window, i) {
    if ((i % 2) === 0) {
      // even windows are unbatched windows
      return window;
    }

    // odd windows are batched
    // collect the entries in an array
    // (e.g. an array of arrays)
    // then use Array.concat() to join
    // them together
    return window
      .toArray()
      .filter(function(array) { return array.length > 0; })
      .map(function(array) {
        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array);
      });
  })
  .concatAll();


stream.subscribe(function(value) {
  console.log("received ", JSON.stringify(value));
});

source.onNext([1, 2, 3]);

source.enterBatchMode();
source.onNext([4]);
source.onNext([5, 6]);
source.onNext([7, 8, 9]);
source.exitBatchMode();

source.onNext([10, 11]);

source.enterBatchMode();
source.exitBatchMode();

source.onNext([12]);

source.enterBatchMode();
source.onNext([13]);
source.onNext([14, 15]);
source.exitBatchMode();
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/master/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

James' comment may provide the answer you're looking for, but I'd like to offer a simple alternative that you may also like.

I read your question as this: "how do I pass a value of type A or type B"?

Answer: Define a type with "either" semantics, which contains data of either type A or type B.

```
var valueOrBuffer = function(value, buffer)
{
  this.Value = value;
  this.Buffer = buffer;
};
var createValue = function(value) { return new valueOrBuffer(value); }
var createBuffer = function(buffer) { return new valueOrBuffer(undefined, buffer); }

stream.OnNext(createValue(1));
stream.OnNext(createValue(2));
stream.OnNext(createValue(3));

stream.OnNext(createBuffer([4, 5, 6]));
```

No switching necessary. Your observer may have to change a bit though:

```
stream.Subscribe(function(v) {
  if (v.Value)
    onNextValue(v.Value);
  else
    onNextBuffer(v.Buffer);
});
```

Comment: After rereading the details of your question it seems that you aren't asking about "single item" vs. "batch" as the title of your question suggests.

Comment: I'll reword my question slightly.

Comment: This won't work because the code that is calling onNext has no knowledge of the mode it is in. Only code higher up the callstack has this knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I realized it after I wrote my answer and reread the details of your question.

Answer (score 0):

A solution... of sorts. After failing to achieve anything with the Window function (from James' linked example) I came up with the following solution, although it is in C# and I have no idea how to translate it to RxJS and Javascript.

If someone can better this using built-in Rx functions, please do so, I'll very much appreciate a better solution.

I have implemented a *BatchedObservable* class that is an observer of type *T* and an observable of type *IEnumerable T*. In normal-mode it wraps each *T* in an array that is passed on. In batch-mode it accumulates *T*s until batch-mode is exited, then it passes on the collected list of batched *T*s.

```
    public class BatchedObservable<T> : IObservable<IEnumerable<T>>, IObserver<T>
    {
        bool batching = false;
        List<T> batchedItems;
        List<IObserver<IEnumerable<T>>> observers = new List<IObserver<IEnumerable<T>>>();

        public void EnterBatchMode()
        {
            batching = true;
            batchedItems = new List<T>();
        }

        public void ExitBatchMode()
        {
            batching = false;
            if (batchedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var observer in observers)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(batchedItems);
                }
            }
            batchedItems = null;
        }


        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<IEnumerable<T>> observer)
        {
            observers.Add(observer);

            return Disposable.Create(() 
                => observers.Remove(observer)
            );
        }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            foreach (var observer in observers)
            {
                observer.OnError(error);
            }
        }

        public void OnNext(T value)
        {
            if (batching)
            {
                batchedItems.Add(value);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var observer in observers)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(new T[] { value });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example usage follows. When running, hit any key to toggle batch mode.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var batched = new BatchedObservable<long>();

        var dataStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        dataStream.Subscribe(batched);

        batched.Subscribe(PrintArray);

        var batchModeEnabled = false;
        while (true)
        { 
            Console.ReadKey();

            batchModeEnabled = !batchModeEnabled;
            if (batchModeEnabled)
            {
                batched.EnterBatchMode();
            }
            else
            {
                batched.ExitBatchMode();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void PrintArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(", ", a.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()) + "]");
    }
```