# How can I "stop" an IObservable from generating notifcations while another IObservable yields specific value?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to model the network connection state with Rx:

- The network connection my go up or down at any moment.
- The network connection is used to send data to a server.
- While the network connection is down, I don't even want to try sending data, rather buffer it until the connection comes up again.

I have two observables:

- `connection` generates `true`/`false` notifications for connection state changes
- `data` generates notifications for data to be sent

While `connection` is up (latest value == `true`) I want `data` notifications to be sent without delay. When the `connection` goes down, I want notifications from `data` to queue up until it goes up again.

Here's a marble diagram of the desired resulting sequence:

```
D = down
U = up

connection D  U    D      U
data       1 2   3  4 5 6
result        12 3        456
```

I've found a solution that feels not right as is saves state in a local variable ([Runnable Gist](https://gist.github.com/agross/c53f5c54fd8c6e163daf)).

```
var data = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var connection = new Subject<bool>();

var connected = false;
connection.Do(x => connected = x).Subscribe();

data
  .Window(() => connection)
  .Subscribe(window =>
  {
    Console.Write("Starting new window: ");
    if (connected == false)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Buffering until online");
      window
        .Buffer(() => connection.Where(x => x))
        .Subscribe(buffered => buffered
                                 .ToObservable()
                                 .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine));
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Forwarding notifications");
      window.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    }
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Coincidence that this question has been asked a few times recently?
[This seems related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431018/how-can-i-alternately-buffer-and-flow-a-live-data-stream-in-rx/23431077#23431077) and 
[so does this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102931/how-to-create-an-rx-rxjs-stream-that-can-be-switched-between-single-item-and-b)

Comment: Many thanks! It seems my Google-fu has failed me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431018/ had the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @AlexanderGroß then close your question and don't just leaving it here sitting as a duplicate.

Comment: Dear @ScottChamberlain, thank you for your helpful comment. I'd like to inform you that I can only vote to close my own question. Which I did right after I wrote my last comment.

Comment: As the author of the post you can click "Delete" instead of "Close" if you want to remove it. (You can not delete questions that have answers with up-votes). But because I have a C# gold badge I can close it as duplicate for you.

Comment: That wasn't obvious at all. So what's the protocol, leave it here for Google to index or delete it (which removes the question?)?