# In Rx, how do I ensure no notifications are lost due to exceptions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to make sure my Rx notifications are not lost when they're processed with my Consumer's `Do` delegate. I have a Producer that generates messages that I need to process, and retry processing if it fails.

Desired marble diagram:

```
Producer   1 2 3 4 5
Consumer   1 X 2 3 X X 4 5
Downstream 1   2 3     4 5
```

The standard `Retry` won't help here since it'll resubscribe to the Producer after an error. This will lose the notification that failed processing and continue with the next notification.

`Retry` marble diagram:

```
Producer  1 2 3 4 5
Consumer  1 X 3 X 5
```

So far, I have this code, but it doesn't seem right to me:

```
static void RetryWithBacklog()
{
  var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToObservable();
  var backlog = new Subject<long>();

  backlog
    .Merge(data)
    .Retry()
    .Do(l =>
    {
      try
      {
        ProcessNotification(l);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        backlog.OnNext(l);
      }
    })
    .Subscribe();

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

([Full code sample](https://gist.github.com/agross/b1dc71aa5ff1f083f919))

### Background

The `Do` operation will perform a network request based on the Producer's notifications. These might fail, so I need to retry it without losing information to be transmitted. Of course I could blindly `while try/catch` the network request, but the requests should not happen as long as the network connection is known to be down (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135517/)).

### Solution

```
static void RetryBeforePassingDownstream()
{
  var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToObservable();

  data
    .Replay(l => l.SelectMany(ProcessNotification).Retry(), 1)
    .Subscribe(Downstream);

  Console.ReadKey();
}

static IObservable<int> ProcessNotification(int notification)
{
  Console.WriteLine("process: {0}", i);
  // either:
  // throw new Exception("error");

  // or:
  return Observable.Return(notification);
}

static void Downstream(int i)
{
  Console.WriteLine("downstream: {0}", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the `Retry` operator is that it works on *cold* observables by resubscribing, thus causing subscription side effects each time that it "retries". For instance, your observable might send a web request each time that an observer subscribes. In your example, the `Retry` operator doesn't make any sense, especially considering that `Interval` never calls `OnError`.

`Retry` semantics can technically exist separately in the observable and the observer. In your situation, couldn't you simply call `ProcessNotification` until it succeeds in the `Do` operator?

Or is your problem simply that downstream observers won't observe the notification when `Do` throws? I guess that's not what you meant, because in that case you could simply swallow the exception.

Or is your problem that there's a chance that the notification will change in some way or get filtered out by upstream operators if the notification were to be replayed? In that case you could probably just use `Do` followed by `Catch` and recursion to achieve the same thing without requiring a `Subject`, but I can't figure out why you'd ever really want to do it.

**Update**

The `Do` operator is not asynchronous. Use `SelectMany` instead so that it's part of your query. That way, cancelling the subscription will also cancel the request. If your request method returns a `Task<T>` instead of an `IObservable<T>`, then consider using the overload that accepts a `CancellationToken` as well.

There's an easier way to make a *cold* observable that replays the last notification and can be retried simply by using the `Retry` operator, as follows.

*(Untested)*

```
data.Replay(r => r.YourStateMachine.SelectMany(SendRequestAsync).Retry(), 1);
```

James' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23431077/3970148) can fill in *YourStateMachine*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the question to provide some background. Does it make it clearer for you? I'm interested in your `Do`/`Catch` with recursion proposal. How could this work? (That topic is entirely new to me.)

Comment: Well `Do` isn't the correct operator for a network request. Try `SelectMany` instead (either the `IObservable<T>` or the `Task<T>` overloads) so that Rx is "aware" of the async operation and so that it can be cancelled via disposing the subscription. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've given what I believe to be a much better answer using `Replay` rather than explicit recursion. But just FYI, in my first answer I was thinking of using `Catch` instead of `Retry` because it allows you to return an observable, which of course could have been a recursive reference to `data`. But after thinking about it for a minute, I realized that it would be something like `data.StartWith(x)`, but then you'd have to be stateful to keep track of the last notification (`x`), which reminded me of `Replay`.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Dave. I just saw it today. I'm trying to code up the YourStateMachine part, but I frankly don't get it. The do-it-while-the-connection-is-up part is (IMHO) not very important to answer this question here. That's the next step, from my point of view. (And I have it solved in a separate demo app.) Can you please explain why YourStateMachine is an extension method of `r`?

Comment: Scratch that. I just omitted the `YourStateMachine` part and magic started happening :) Many, many thanks for helping me!

Comment: I'm have trouble adding the `YourStateMachine` part. The `Window` used the the code James suggested will always start in the "offline" state when my `Retry` catches an exception. What do you think, should I post another question?